# Cant access array elements outside a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, hash

I am trying to hash the name together with the path of all the files from a specific directory. After hashing I am saving the hash into the array(hash_orig). Here is what I have done.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Hashes = require('jshashes');
var path = process.argv[2];
var path_elements = new Array();
var hash_orig = new Array();


fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
console.log('\nNumber of files in the directory: '+items.length);
console.log('Hashing algorithm: SHA1')
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        path_elements.push(path+"/"+items[i])
        var SHA1 = new Hashes.SHA1().b64(path_elements[i])
        console.log([i+1]+':\t'+items[i]+"\t" + SHA1)
        hash_orig.push(SHA1);
    }
});

    console.log(hash_orig)
```

**The problem:**

The problem is that when I am pushing the hash into the `hash_orig` array and trying to access it outside the function `fs.readdir` the array `hash_orig` is empty. (`console.log(hash_orig)`)

I need to access it outside in order to perform further some comparison operation to determine if the hash has been changed to Verifying Integrity of the files name and path.
What I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are simply missing that your `fs.readdir` function is a **asynchronous** callback.

Thus, when you call `console.log(hash_orig)`, from outside, in fact the callback isnt completed yet.

Use a timeout and your array will filled :

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(hash_orig);
},500);
```

Answer (score 4):

`fs.readdir`is a async function. At the time when `console.log(hash_orig)`is reached, the callback of `readdir` is not called yet.
Put the log-statement at the end of your callback and you will see the results.